# Program that takes a list of numbers 1- 1000, reverses them , puts them into a file (called my_file) and prints them back into my_file

Tags: python, list, file, reverse

okay, so im trying to write a program that takes a list of numbers 1 to 1000, reverses them, puts them into a file (my_file), and prints them back into the file.
so far, my code looks like this:

`new_list = list(range(1001))
 my_file = open("text.txt", "w")
 for x in (reversed(new_list)):
     my_file.write(x)`

And, I know im doing something wrong, im just not sure what (although it probably has to do with the last line of coding?)

PS, sorry if this question is worded awfully, this is my first time using stackoverflow to ask a question :)

Comment: Just replace `my_file.write(x)` by `my_file.write('%d\n' %x)`. You need to define the format while writing. The newline character `\n` writes every number in a new line in the file. Also,  put `my_file.close()` after the `for` loop.

Comment: Alternatively, you can also use `my_file.write('{}\n'.format(x))`

Comment: `x` is an `int` so you'd need to `str(x)` to be able to print it.  You'll also need to `print("\n")` to put a new line in.